# How can I better place cities around procedurally generated terrain?

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor, procedural-generation

I'm making a terrain/map generator. The terrain generation works fine, but a problem arises when placing cities around the terrain. I place cities on given terrain depending on the terrain's moisture, temperature, soil quality, and underground mineral prevalence. Naturally, the optimal terrain will have the next-to-optimal terrain very nearby, so my cities appear in clusters, like so (cities are red dots):

[image]

The solution I'm leaning towards is identifying if two cities are within a certain defined distance of each other, and if they are, move one of the cities to a location clear of other cities. My questions are:

1. Is that the best approach for spreading out cities?
2. If so, what technique can I use to determine how close two cities are (I read about nearest neighbor searches and it looked very promising, maybe that)?

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Have you considered modifying the terrain generator to increase the amount of optimal terrains? If this number is a lot bigger than the number of cities you are placing, then there will be very few (if any) collisions.

Comment: I learned a lot in this area by browsing the source code to the Civ IV SDK. In your case, "city locations" would relate to how they choose starting positions for each player/AI. Find good terrain/resources, spread out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would lower the constrains for possible city-locations. Calculate a probability for each position for a city.

Than set a city by random according to the probabilities of all locations not yet occupied by cities.

Than lower the probabilities around the new set city (within a certain radius, Near the city lower the probabilities a lot (or even set them ti 0) and only lower then less with increasing distance.

This way the cities should be spread around your terrain quite naturally.

**Example** (very little one) How to take the next location:
You have 3 possible locations with probabilities 0.9, 0,2 and 0.4
Now sum up the probabilities 0.9 + 0.2 + 0.4 = 1.5
now take a random number between 0 and 1.5.

```
0   .. 0.9 take the first location  
0.9 .. 1.1 take the second location  
1.1 .. 1.5 take the third location
```

Comment: Possible modification / implementation - insert the probabilities (well, 'fitness' in this case) into a heap and simply pick the most probable at each step (or, if you don't just want the most probable, insert into a BST and iterate through to pick).

Comment: Another possible modification - divide the grid into (for example) 3x3 grids. For each of these, only use the most fit location as a possible location and, from there, do your algorithm as described.

Comment: @Dukeling: You should not 'simply pick the most probable at each step'    . Weight each location with its probability and than take one by random (of cause the one with the high probability are more likely to be chosen).

Comment: You *can* pick the most probable *if you want* (in that case it won't be probabilities any more, but rather just some fitness measures, and you'd have a deterministic algorithm). Depending on the application, this may be acceptable, or even desired. But I did say "if you don't just want the most probable...".

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

If you have only few cities, whenever you are considering adding a new one, just calculate the distance from the new site to the existing cities, and do not add the city if the distance is lower than a threshold you set.

If you have lots of cities, allocate a mask of the same size as the original map grid, and whenever you add a city, mark all points near that city as "occupied" meaning that you can't add a new city to those. Basically, you set the suitability of a terrain point near existing city to zero by marking that in the mask. Create a disk shaped mask for best results. If you want, you can use a floodfill starting from the city then to fill the disk mask only through land routes, so that the influence of a city stops to one side of a river, say. (Think of Buda and Pest).